# De-bounce calls based on dispatch loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

Recent React.JS Conf had Flux panel and Kyle Davis [mentioned](http://youtu.be/LTj4O7WJJ98?t=8m20s) de-bounce calls based on dispatch loop optimization. Can anyone provide some examples on how to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that it looks something like this:

```
function debounce(duration) {
    var _timer = null;
    var toCall = [];

    function dispatch() {
        _timer = null;
        toCall.forEach(function(opts) {
            if (opts.shouldCall) {
                opts.fn.apply(undefined, opts.args);
            }
            opts.shouldCall = false;
        });
    }

    return function debounce(fn) {
        var myAction = {fn: fn, args: [], shouldCall: false};
        toCall.push(myAction);

        return function() {
            myAction.shouldCall = true;
            myAction.args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

            clearTimeout(_timer);
            _timer = setTimeout(dispatch, duration);
        };
    };
}
```

This looks quite complicated, but all it really is is a trailing-only shared debounce.  Multiple functions are debounced on the same timer, and all are called in the same tick.  The most recent arguments are preserved (not needed in this specific case, but it's not going to cause problems).

We create one of these for all (not each) of our stores.  The duration is mostly arbitrary, but is long enough to allow the browser to render a frame between us doing our store update logic, and the UI updating which may make scrolling feel more responsive.

```
var storeDebounce = debouncer(20);
```

In our stores, instead of this:

```
  emitChange: function() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },
```

We do this:

```
  emitChange: storeDebounce(function() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  }.bind(this)),
```

Now if a store or stores are updated multiple times in the same tick, or short succession (often happens with promises or other guaranteed asynchronous code), we'll only emit a single change event for each affected store.

<sup>disclaimer: not tested</sup>

Comment: Can you please shed a light a little bit on `We create one of these for all (not each) of our stores`?

Comment: @message, otherwise you'd have a difference setTimeout for each store's change event, and they'd all be sent out after each other, possibly causing the some components to have outdated data and even errors that should be impossible.  The #1 important thing in optimizing is that you don't break anything following best practices (#2 is not breaking anything, but that's allowed sometimes).

Comment: so, you need to have only one  `emitChange: storeDebounce` for all stores?! Where it should be defined to affect all stores? Can you add some examples using 2 stores and shared emitchange (if it's working the way i think)?

Comment: @message, it's just a function, so you can figure out how you want to provide it to the stores (put it in a module, pass it from main.js when initializing them, use a DI framework, etc.)

Comment: Does `loadash` or `underscore` debouncer differ from your implementation?

Comment: They're more flexible, e.g. in lodash you can have trailing only (default), leading only, or both; configure the maximum time to wait, and a bunch of other things.  This version is domain specific.  Also they don't have any way to share a debounce between multiple functions, otherwise I would have implemented it in terms of lodash debounce.

Comment: i wrote you an email, not sure if you received it.